# My android system and android os are consuming more part of my battery

Tags: battery

this problem has been troublimg me from the last few weeks I reported this problem at the Flipkart service center and they changed my battery and software.I even tried a factory reset but to no avail. i charged my phone in the afternoon . it lasted for aday and ahalf .while i was going to sleep the battery was about 58%..when i got up in the morning the battery was only 5%. I am completely tired.Please help me resolve this deadlock
Ashish Tiwari

Comment: Which phone you are using? What is your android os version?

Comment: Well, what I can advise you over here's call down the place where you purchase it from and ask them for replacement or the better option would be walking down towards the nearest support and tell them to replace the battery as I am somewhere getting a feel that the problem is with the battery.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the following services

- Google Now (if you dont use it much)
- Developer options (off)
- Location Reporting (off)
- Background Wifi Scanning (off)
- Brightness - low
- Remove unwanted apps

Once you have disabled these services, restart the device .

Answer (score 0):

So the battery usage information is usage since the last time you unplugged at about a full charge. Something is going to use the battery. People worry too much about "why is using 40% of my battery" but that is not actually the case. It is using 40% of the about of power that has drained since you unplugged your phone.

So if your battery is at 90%, and the OS used 40% of your battery, it used 4% battery. while other applications are responsible for the other 6% of the drain. The phone is going to use battery, if you are sleeping or not. The phone still connects to the mobile carrier, gets its signal strength, apps like facebook, google+, etc, all communicate with their "host" and other mobile data related things.

The best thing to do, if you don't put your phone on the charger at night, is to turn on airplane mode. I do it when I can't put my phone on the charger, and when I wake up, it is only down maybe 1%.